# Error List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> with dio helper to get data

Tags: flutter

I am currently building an app to read data through an api and I am trying to parse a JSON api from JSON Placeholder.

in the cubit i use dio helper

```
void getHomeData()
  {
    emit(ShopLoadingHomeDataScreen());

    DioHelperr.getData(
        url: Product,
    ).then((value) {


      productModel=ProductModelJson.fromJson(value!.data);

      printFullText(productModel!.name.toString());

      emit(ShopSuccessHomeDataScreen());}

      ).catchError((error){

      print(error.toString());

      emit(ShopErrorHomeDataScreen());});

  }
```

my model i used app.quicktype.io

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<ProductModelJson> productModelJsonFromJson(String str) => List<ProductModelJson>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => ProductModelJson.fromJson(x)));

String productModelJsonToJson(List<ProductModelJson> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ProductModelJson {
  ProductModelJson({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.cost,
    this.discount,
    this.image,
    this.rfidCode,
    this.description,
    this.category,
    this.idCategory,
    this.prand,
    this.count,
    this.sellername,
  });

  int? id;
  String? name;
  int? cost;
  int? discount;
  String? image;
  String? rfidCode;
  String? description;
  String? category;
  int? idCategory;
  String? prand;
  int? count;
  String? sellername;

  factory ProductModelJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductModelJson(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    cost: json["cost"],
    discount: json["discount"],

    image: json["image"],
    rfidCode: json["rfidCode"],
    description: json["description"],
    category: json["category"],
    idCategory: json["idCategory"],
    prand: json["prand"],
    count: json["count"],
    sellername: json["sellername"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "cost": cost,
    "discount": discount,
    "image": image,
    "rfidCode": rfidCode,
    "description": description,
    "category": category,
    "idCategory": idCategory,
    "prand": prand,
    "count": count,
    "sellername": sellername,
  };
}
```

The error i am currently running into is:

Error type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

[image]

This is the JSON information i'm trying to read although its only a small part of it:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Italiano - Size 400gm Ziti",
    "cost": 12,
    "discount": 0,
    "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71C0osWbaeS._AC_SY879_.jpg",
    "rfidCode": "1D 2D DB 4A 64 00 00",
    "description": "Italiano - Size 400gm Ziti",
    "category": "foods",
    "idCategory": 4,
    "prand": "Italiano ",
    "count": 100,
    "sellername": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Italiano Serpentini 400G",
    "cost": 12,
    "discount": 0,
    "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71qoUQKcJIS._AC._SR360,460.jpg",
    "rfidCode": "1D 2D DB 4A 64 00 00",
    "description": "Italiano Serpentini 400G",
    "category": "foods",
    "idCategory": 4,
    "prand": "Italiano ",
    "count": 100,
    "sellername": "string"
  },
```

How do i rectify this error?

Comment: Does it start with `[` and end with `]`. If yes then it's a list.

Comment: Yes the Json information that 8 get start with [  ] but what i showd do or where is the wrong?

Comment: `productModel=ProductModelJson.fromJson(value!.data);` to `productModel=ProductModelJson.fromJson(value!.data[0]);`

Comment: but i want to get all data not only the first one